# creatures of men of large views or creatures of large views

Tags: idiomatic-language

> Large thoughts at times are creatures of men of large views.

or

> Large thoughts at times are creatures of large views.

what's the idiomatic expression or what's better?

Comment: Neither is idiomatic, in my opinion.

Comment: Men may have large views (although **large** is an awkward modifier) but creatures do not have large views.  The first is clumsy; the second is improbable.

Comment: What about: Large thoughts at times are  creatures of shade.

Comment: Can't women have large views?

Comment: Here men mean human beings

Comment: That is very old fashioned and may be offensive to many in Western countries.